# How do you access AWS services within a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-functions

I need to access DynamoDB from within a Google Cloud Function (GCF).

Using **Lambda**, getting the necessary AWS creds to access other AWS services are of course straightforward with IAM as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html).

With **Heroku**, I've used process.env as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

```
AWS.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

With **Cloud Foundry**, I've used a User Provided Service as described [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/14/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/):

```
cf cups aws-creds-service -p "{\"accessKeyId\": \"XYZ\",\"secretAccessKey\": \"ABC\"}"
cf bind-service my-app aws-creds-service
```

Within my **GCF** I've tried the following with no success:

```
AWS.WebIdentityCredentials,
sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity,
AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials
```

I don't need any data from the the user, so I don't really even want to be going down the road of web identity federation. I just want to use my AWS creds without hard coding them into the GCF. How best to go about this?

Comment: Access to external HTTP services is only possible for projects on a paid plan, to prevent anonymous abuse. Is the project you run the functions in on a paid plan?

Comment: Thanks Frank. Yes, I confirmed that billing is enabled on this project.

Comment: Hopefully someone will have something better, but in the meantime I'll just be importing a local JSON file as Cloud Function dependency:   `AWS.config.loadFromPath('./AWSconfig.json')`. Or, for someone not using AWS but looking for a basic similar solution, `const cert = require ('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')`. I'd like to avoid this though to enable CI/CD via auto deploy following github pushes (since of course config files with creds don't belong on repos).

Comment: In theory it should be possible to use Cloud KMS to encrypt secrets into Cloud Storage and decrypt when you read them out, which at least keeps them out of the repo and gives you an audit trail if someone's being sneaky.

OTOH, there's too much security through obscurity for me at the moment - I'm failing to decrypt within the Cloud Function, possibly because you can't assign custom scopes to the compute engine instances they're running on...